# Magento 2 : Knockoutjs data-bind not Working in Inner Loop

Tags: knockoutjs, knockout

**Case 1:** -- **Working**

**HTML**

```
Test::<span data-bind="text: $parent.testText"></span>
<button  data-bind="click: $parent.testbtn"></button>
```

**JS**

```
numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
incrementClickCounter : function() {
 alert('click called..');
 var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
 this.numberOfClicks("Testtttt....");
}
```

**Case 2:** -- **Working**

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: loop1(), as: 'styleColor'} -->
 Test::<span data-bind="text: $parent.testText"></span>
 <button  data-bind="click: $parent.testbtn"></button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Case 3:** -- **Not working**

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: loop1(), as: 'styleColor'} -->
 <div class="standard-color" data-bind="foreach: $parent.loop2()">                    
     Test::<span data-bind="text: $parent.testText"></span>
     <button  data-bind="click: $parent.testbtn"></button>
 </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When i click on button, js function not calling.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have added an additional layer, so `$parent` is now referencing the inner loop not the outer loop. To access the outer loop again try `$parents[1]`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069381/access-parents-parent-in-knockout-view-nesting-context for more info.

Comment: Thanks, It's working ....

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348128/magento-2-knockoutjs-data-bind-issue-in-inner-loop